# Retrieve and manage db data

Tags: delphi, firebird

I have a TSQLQuery component, called qryUltimoProyectoCreado, with the next query:

```
select gen_id(GEN_PROYECTO_ID, 0)
from rdb$database;
```

The query component have a TDataSet, called dsUltimoProyectoCreado.
Now, in my code, i need execute que query (Open) and manipulate the retrieved rows:

```
DMConnect.qryUltimoProyectoCreado.Open;
{ now ? }
```

Any ideas ? im novice in Delphi. Thanks !.

Comment: Do you call gen_id() with step=0 intentionaly? BTW, starting FB 2.0 the recommended way to generate a new value is **select next value for <Generator> from rdb$database** [http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-genid.html](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-genid.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work with the query [`Fields`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Fields) property:

```
DMConnect.qryUltimoProjyectoCread.Open;
if not DMConnect.qryUltimoProjyectoCread.IsEmpty then
  NewID := DMConnect.qryUltimoProjyectoCread.Fields[0].AsInteger;
```

It's better if you give your columns (especially those that are the result of a function or stored procedure) an alias in your SQL:

```
DMConnect.qryUltimoProjyectoCread.SQL.Text := 'select gen_id(GEN_PROYECTO_ID, 0)' +
                                              ' as NewID from rdb$database;';
DMConnect.qryUltimoProjyectoCread.Open;
if not DMConnect.qryUltimoProjyectoCread.IsEmpty then    
  MyNewID := DMConnect.qryUltimoProjyectoCread.FieldByName('NewID').AsInteger;
```

There are some links at the bottom of the documentation page I linked above that show how to work with data in Delphi that you may find useful.